# R with tcltk: How to compile Tcl/Tk's "Img" package for Windows 64 Bit?

Tags: r, windows, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using **R3.2.3 64 Bit Version on Windows 7**.

The R installation comes with Tcl/Tk and I can find some preinstalled Tcl/Tk packages (Tktable, dde1.3 and reg1.2) in the installation path:

```
/R/R-3.2.3/Tcl/lib64/
```

I want to use the **[Img package of Tcl/Tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1404) to process JPG pictures** but this package is only available as source code:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkimg/

**How can I compile the Img source for the installed version of R** and how do I install the binaries so that I can use the Img package in R with the R package tcltk?

I would guess I could use **[RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)** somehow...

*PS: Also nice to know would be: Are the binaries compatible with other versions of R (or better: The preinstalled Tcl/Tk versions)?*

Comment: I have installed RTools, downloaded and unzipped the sources of Img and called `sh ./configure`. This results in the error message `chmod: not found` `configure: error: cannot create configure.lineno: rerun with a POSIX shell`. I am afraid I have to install minGW too...

Comment: I found instructions on how to compile Tcl/Tk on Windows using Visual C++: http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html (see link [How to Compile Tcl Source Releases] (http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html) in there). There you can also find how to compile Tcl extensions for Windows using the [TEA feature] (http://wiki.tcl.tk/327)(see Sean McKnight's comment!). Since R seems to be compiled with gcc (installed together with RTools) I suppose you have to use the configure option "—enable-gcc" (source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/tcl-tk/tk_environment.htm).